# flutter run cannot access files of my secondary hard disk

Tags: linux, flutter, ubuntu

I have a SSD and a HDD in my system.I am using ssd for store ubuntu and windows and saving my project files in HDD. But i flutter cant access files in the HDD.
It is throwing this error message

Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "FileSystemException: Cannot delete file,
path = '/path to project/.flutter-plugins' (OS Error:
Read-only file system, errno = 30)".
Unable to generate crash report due to secondary error: FileSystemException: Cannot create file, path = '/path to project/flutter_01.log' (OS Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30)
Please report a bug at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.

Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "FileSystemException: Cannot delete file,
path = '/path to project/.flutter-plugins' (OS Error:
Read-only file system, errno = 30)".
Unable to generate crash report due to secondary error: FileSystemException: Cannot create file, path = '/path to project/flutter_01.log' (OS Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30)
Please report a bug at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
Unhandled exception:
ProcessExit: 1
#0      _handleToolError (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:172:7)

#1      run.. (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:86:7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My secondary harddisk was mounting as read only file system.
I have remounted it to solve the issue.